# How to determine if a function was called with `.call` or `.apply`?

Tags: javascript, this, babeljs

I created this function so that I could chain methods together:

```
export default function bindable(fn) {
    return function boundFn(...args) {
        return this === undefined ? fn(...args) : fn(this, ...args);
    }
}
```

It works with the [bind operator](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/). For example, you can define a new function like,

```
 export const flatten = bindable(arrayOfArrays => Array.prototype.concat(...arrayOfArrays));
```

And then use it like this:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]::flatten()
```

*Or* like this:

```
flatten([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

[Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Cstage-0&targets=Node-8&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=true&experimental=true&loose=true&spec=false&code=function%20bindable(fn)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20boundFn(...args)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%20%26%26%20args.length%20%3C%20fn.length%20%3F%20this%3A%3Afn(this%2C%20...args)%20%3A%20this%3A%3Afn(...args)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20flatten%20%3D%20bindable(arrayOfArrays%20%3D%3E%20Array.prototype.concat(...arrayOfArrays))%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%5B4%2C5%2C6%5D%5D%3A%3Aflatten())%3B%0Aconsole.log(flatten(%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%5B4%2C5%2C6%5D%5D))%3B)

This worked great at first until I realized that if I use it like in the second scenario, but import the helper method as a module, it breaks the context!

```
 import * as Arr from './array-helper-methods';
 Arr.flatten([1,2,3]); // `this` is now `Arr`
```

So my question is: **is there any way that I can reliably detect if a function is called with the bind operator?**

Comment: Why `Array.prototype.concat` instead of just `[...arrayOfArrays]`? I also suspect this is unanswerable as it would depend on implementation details of the bind operator and I don't recall anything in the spec that would enable that level of introspection. I'd love to be proven wrong though.

Comment: @JaredSmith That's not really relevant to the question, but also.... it doesn't work. `> [...arrayOfArrays]
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ]
> Array.prototype.concat(...arrayOfArrays)
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
`

Comment: @mpen Can you elaborate on what you're doing this for? Why do you need your functions to work both as methods and as pure functions? If you're trying to make it so you can call any method with bind syntax, wouldn't it be simpler to just make a function that takes a pure function and turns it into one using `this`? Then you can just call that on any pure function you may import. If you're going to be using the bind syntax anyway, why do you need the function to still work without a `this` context?

Comment: @sbking That's essentially what `bindable` does, no? Takes a pure function and makes it callable with `this` -- except if `this` is undefined, then it lets you call it the 'pure' way as well. If I removed the `this` check it'd work unambiguously but then I'd need two versions of each function, which is just a PITA to manage.

Comment: @mpen Why is it a pain to manage? It looks like you're doing this so that you can use a function exclusively with the bind syntax. You can still have the reference to the original version of the function which you pass to `bindable`, so you already have two versions of the function. I guess I don't understand why you want to use the function in two different ways in the same module file. That sounds confusing.

Comment: @sbking Because this is going into a library. *Both* the `bindable` function *and* the array functions. I don't want to have to force the consumer to wrap every function they want to use with `bindable` before they can start chaining. My library exports them pre-wrapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a large and yet unsolved problem of the bind operator. But no, it only works for methods. You just should **provide two versions** of your functions if you want to support both styles.

Doing it dynamically is hard. No, you cannot detect whether the function was called using `()`, as a method, was bound, with `call` or `apply` etc. And you really shouldn't be able to anyway.

For your case, I'd choose

```
function bindable(fn, isContext) {
    return function boundFn(...args) {
        return isContext(this) ? fn(this, ...args) : fn(...args);
    }
}
export default bindable(bindable, f => typeof f == "function");
```

Then you can use `bindable(flatten, Array.isArray)` or `flatten::bindable(Array.isArray)` for `flatten`. For more complicated cases, you can also incorporate the arity of the function, i.e. whether `fn.length + 1 == args.length`.

Comment: That gets hairy when I write a function that operates on arbitrary objects, no? Also if the consumer calls it on the wrong variable type, error checking goes out the window because the function will just be called without a context.

Comment: Yes. But the whole idea of having a function that copes with being called with multiple signatures is hairy, that's why I recommend two separate functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a workaround than a real solution, but you can check if `this` contains a `flatten` property:

```
export default function bindable(fn) {
    return function boundFn(...args) {
        return (this === undefined || 'flatten' in this) ? fn(...args) : fn(this, ...args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if that were reliable, it's not generic enough. `bindable` should work with every module, not just my array-helpers module. Actually... I wonder if sniffing for `__esModule` would work?

Comment: @mpen No, as that's a transpiler artefact. Never use it

Answer (score 1):

A more generic (but not so good performance-wise) solution would be to check if any method of `this` is the `boundFn` function:

```
export default function bindable(fn) {
    return function boundFn(...args) {
        return (this == null || Object.values(this).some(x => x === boundFn))
            ? fn(...args)
            : fn(this, ...args);
    }
}
```

Comment: But `Arr.flatten` is not a bound function? Also I don't see where the name "`boundFn`" comes from.

Comment: @Bergi `Arr.flatten` is a bound function, because it's a result of passing the actual function to `bindable`. And `boundFn` is the name of the function returned by `bindable`.

Comment: Ah, I see now. It's not a "bound function" which are special functions created by the builtin `.bind()` method, that's what confused me. To check whether it's the function returned by `bindable`, I wouldn't check for its name but for identity instead: `.every(x => x != boundFn)`